# Trello API via javascript with Trello object

Tags: javascript, rest, trello

I'm trying to fire a put request to move a trello Card to another list without success, I can change the name and due date, but not the list.

It's a very simple code, I don't know what's wrong with my code.
I believe idList value is right, I create a card in the target list and typed .json just to check the idList and this is the result :

[image]

so, any thoughts that may help ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://api.trello.com/1/client.js?key=********************************&token=****************************************************************"></script>

<body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      Trello.put('/cards/5772bc30da92129b953111bd', {
        name: 'test change name 1'
      }); // works normally
      Trello.put('/cards/5772bc30da92129b953111bd', {
        due: '07/01/2016'
      }); // works normally
      Trello.put('/cards/5772bc30da92129b953111bd', {
        idList: '576eee0460bbb196ccc48d37'
      }); //doesn't work
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Solution : thank you guys for try to help me, i figure out the solution.**

I'm forgetting to mention that i'm sending the card to another board, so it's necessary to inform idBoard with the request :

```html
Trello.put('/cards/5772bc30da92129b953111bd', 
  {idBoard: '576eed9a21fa5781af4edf5b'}
  {idList: '576eee0460bbb196ccc48d37'}); // works fine!
```

After inform the idBoard works fine, thank you again!

Comment: I suggest you to print the error, so we can understand what's wrong: `Trello.put(link, {idList: xxx}, function () {}, function(err) {console.log(err)})`

Comment: Thank you @rpadovani, i did what you said, the return is : 

Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "invalid id", status: 400, statusText: "error"}

Comment: i know that the message 'invalid id' is self explanatory, but the idList is right, and the idCard is also right, i'm clueless...

Comment: is the list in the same board the card is? Maybe you have to change the board as well...

Comment: You're right, can you post a answer ? i'll accept as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're moving the card in a list that belongs to another board, you have to change the boardId value as well.

I also suggest you to always check the value that is returned on error by Trello, it is the 4th argument of the call - you need to pass a function that will be used as callback on error!

Answer (score 0):

from API docs it seem idList value should be

> id of the list the card should be moved to

[check Here](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card#put-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink)

in Your code should change value of

> '576eee0460bbb196ccc48d37'

to the id value of list where you want to move your card.

this id value will be same for app card belong to that list

Comment: Hello Rajesh, thank you, but the id '576eee0460bbb196ccc48d37' is the value of the target list, the card should move to '576eee0460bbb196ccc48d37'

Comment: can you confirm that value '576eee0460bbb196ccc48d37' is idList of target id, it should be same in all cards belongs to that list

Comment: Yes Rajesh , i folow the procedure under the "Finding a List ID" topic in this page https://developers.trello.com/get-started/start-building. Just created a card in target list, open the card and typed .json at the end of the link.

Comment: I have tried this in trello UI and checked all value in Developer toolbar it is working fine. can you do same for your case and see what value is passing in developer toolbar.